# How does Sand Wraith's Ultimate work?

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

Sand Wraith Ultimate let you create illusions that attacks your enemies and you can switch to whoever you want to hunt. I don't know how to make that switch or the teleport! I've purchased HoN since it was closed beta I am not a newbie but all this time I never figured how this ultimate work.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To activate Sand Wraiths ultimate, press R.
An illusion will be created for every alive enemy hero, and it will follow them around.

To swap positions with an illusion, press R again and click on the minimap near where you want to go to. You will swap positions with the illusion closest to where you clicked.